# Deviation on a prism for small angles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

So, I posted this question on PSE, since it is a demonstration about geometrical optics. But (heh), my questioning is entirely reduced to a purely geometrical demonstration, so, I think it's suitable here. I'll just copy and paste it, since I think there's not much more to add. It goes like this:

Consider the following scheme for monochromatic light refracting through a prism, with the deviation angle $\delta$:

[image]

Let $\theta_1\ \wedge\ \alpha\ll1$ . I'm trying to prove that, under those conditions, the following approximation is valid:
\begin{equation}
\delta=\alpha(\eta-1)
\end{equation}
where $\eta$ is the refractive index of the prism. Using the direction of both $\hat{n}$ and $\hat{n}'$, we could get other two triangles:

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4ogG.png)

From which we get:
\begin{align}
(I)&\ \phi'=\pi-(\theta+\theta')\\
(II)&\ \delta+\phi'=\pi\\
(III) &\ \phi=\pi-(\theta_2+\theta'_2)\\
(IV)&\ \theta_1=\theta_2+\theta\\
(V)&\ \theta'_1=\theta'_2+\theta'.
\end{align}

Using $(I),(II)$, and then $(IV),(V)$:
\begin{equation}
\delta=\theta+\theta'\implies\delta= (\theta_1+\theta'_1)-(\theta_2+\theta'_2).
\end{equation}
Using Snell's law for both refractions, considering that there's air in the prism's surroundings:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sin\theta'_1}{\sin\theta'_2}=\eta=\frac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2}\simeq\frac{\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2}
\end{equation}
where we used the (in)famous approximation $\sin\theta_1\simeq\theta_1$ since $\theta_1\ll1$. Using $(IV)$, we take this into account again to derive:
\begin{equation}
\theta_1\ll1\implies \theta+\theta_2<<1\implies\theta\ \wedge \theta_2\ll1\implies\sin\theta_2\simeq\theta_2\implies\eta\simeq\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}
\end{equation}
since both $\theta$ and $\theta_2$ are positive-defined. Let's get a relation for $\alpha$ now. For that, we highlight the quadrilateral:

[image]

Therefore:
\begin{equation}
\alpha+\phi=\pi
\end{equation}
because of the normal unit vectors. Using $(II)$:
\begin{equation}
\alpha=\theta_2+\theta'_2\implies \theta_2+\theta'_2<<1\implies\theta_2\ \wedge\ \theta'_2\ll1
\end{equation}
since $\alpha\ll1$. Because of that, we can approximate $\alpha$ to either $\theta_2$ or $\theta'_2$. Note that we can approximate $\theta_2+\theta'_2\simeq\theta_2$ and rewrite $\delta$:
\begin{equation}
\delta=\theta_1+\theta'_1-\theta_2
\end{equation}
And that's where I got stuck. If we could derive that $\theta'_1\ll1$, the approximation would be valid:
\begin{equation}
\theta_1+\theta'_1+\theta_2\simeq\theta_2\implies\delta=\theta_1+\theta_2
\end{equation}
And we would be done. Note that:
\begin{equation}
\delta=\theta_2\left(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}-1\right)\simeq\alpha(\eta-1)
\end{equation}
Where we used $\alpha\simeq\theta_2$. That would conclude the derivation. Thing is, I've not been able to prove that $\theta'_1\ll1$. I've tried using the other approximations I've shown, but you can't really get rid of it.

Any tip, corrections, or help of any kind are welcome. Thanks in advance!